# Sharepoint 2010: people search is not working

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010

I followed the directions in this *link and the while the "all sites" search is working, the "people" search is not working. Do I need to configure a content source (nothing seems to make sense: sharepoint sites, web sites, file shares, exchange public folders, line of business data, custom repository)? Under the search central admin > service application > View Scopes, the "people" section items column indicate 0 but the "all sites" items column indicate 243.

*link: http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-enterprise-search-sharepoint-2010/

Is getting people search really this hard out of the box? I didn't configure the installation, maybe there is a piece missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your content source.  The default content source typically includes all SharePoint sites and people.  If you created your search app before your user profile app, then you may not have that in the content source.  You should see an address starting with sps3://.

Make sure you have users to crawl in your profile db.

Try doing a full crawl on the source that contains people.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you user profile service import is running fine, check the MSDN doc: [Configure profile synchronization (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx) for step to step guidance.